# Have Bash to parse multiple space-contained words connected by escape char \

Tags: string, bash, whitespace

How within a string, can we have Bash to parse multiple space-contained words connected by escape char `\`, by the simplest way (1-2 commands/lines) ?

```
s="English phrases must be understood are as\ well, even\ if, as\ such"
```

How to achieve kind of in few variables (or enclosed by quote pair instead of double quote):

```
a="English"
b="phrases"
c="must"
d="be"
e="understood"
f="are"
g="as well,"
h="even if,"
i="as such"
```

or as array of s variable itself, etc.  Please guide to the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
read -a arr <<< "$s"
```

`read` relies on `IFS` split words. If you have modified that variable,
prepend `IFS=' '` to the command above.

```sh
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
English
phrases
must
be
understood
are
as well,
even if,
as such
```